# Handling Alert in webdriver 2.21and mozilla11

Tags: java, webdriver, alert, mozilla

I am using Firefox 11 + WebDriver 2.21.0 / WebDriver 2.22.0 (tried both).

In my scenario, when I click on a tab, it opens a confirmation box and on clicking `OK` it starts loading the new tab from server.

So I'm handling this scenario as:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myTab")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

but after it clicks on "mytab", it waits for window to load indefinitely. So it is not coming on `alert.accept()` and browser waits to accept the confirmation dialog to load the new page, so I end up in a deadlock condition.

This code works well in Internet Explorer.

Please help, how to deal the situation?

Answer (score 0):

You, sir, might have found a bug (or at least an inconsistency) in Selenium WebDriver.

Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list) whether it's been found before, and if there's no such bug, feel free [to file it](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry).

In the meantime, you can try [loading `FirefoxDriver` with "unstable" loading strategy](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) and then (if it's not enough) possibly [`driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) (which works only for Firefox with the "unstable" setting).

<del>As a workaround, you can try clicking the tab via JavaScript - though I'm not sure whether it will or won't work:</del>

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('myTab').click()");
```

---

**Edit:**

What you could do as another workaround (inspired by Selenium RC), you can temporarily disable confirmation dialogs...

```
// assuming your driver can handle JS ;)
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// stores the original confirm() function and replaces it
js.executeScript("window.originalConfirm = window.confirm;" 
        + "window.confirm = function(m) { return true; };");

driver.findElement(By.id("myTab")).click();
// it should not even fire the confirm and just proceed

// get the confirm back
js.executeScript("window.confirm = window.originalConfirm;");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Slanec. I tried using ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element); but it also waits in the same way.

Comment: and when i tried using driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(). systen is not able to detect page load complete even after page is loaded it keeps on waiting and time out after specified time.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I guess it's a bug, then.

Comment: Thanks it worked as a workaround on mozilla. same is not working in ie8. it throws modaldialogException after clicking "myTab". This way same test case won't be able to run on both browser.